# Number ladder and lateral pyramid in c#

Tags: c#

I have to program a c# console app that when given a number as a "height"
prints a number ladder like the one below:

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234

As well as a second program that prints when given, say 5 as height:

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234
>
> 12345
>
> 1234
>
> 12
>
> 1

I've got no idea where to start, I know I'm supposed to use for cycles but as it's my second c# class ever, I'm a bit lost. Just to be clear, I'm not asking someone else to do my homework, but I could appreciate some pointers.
EDIT: so I've got this so far on the first task:

```
int altura; string space = "";
Console.WriteLine("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= altura; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        space = "";
        space = space + Convert.ToString(j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(space);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

And now it works.
But I still can't figure out how to make it loop back.
EDIT # 2: And It works now both!!!
Thank you all so much!

Edit#3
So sorry to ask, but if i wanted to make it print:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
```

when my height is 4 i should just modify the second loop correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reset `space` on each line

```
int altura; 
Console.WriteLine("Dar altura: ");
altura = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= altura; i++)
{
  string space = "";
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
  {
    space = space + Convert.ToString(j);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(space);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Then add another double loop that counts down `i` from `alture-1` to `1`

```
for (int i = altura-1; i >= 1; i--)
{
  ...
}
```

with the same contents as above.

Comment: Thanks, done and now it works. The first part of the assignment anyay. I still can't figure out  how to make it loop back.

Comment: I just told you. After the first part add another nested `for` loop but counting down.

Comment: Silly me didnt see it thanks! Wait is the second nested loop inside the first two?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I guess I'm a bit burnt out from today, but I finally did it.

Comment: Do me a favor and next time you look at _your_ code, see what blocks of code are just copies of each other. Use this to decide what code should be in a function (in order to be re-used again and again). That would be your first step in learning how to structure programs which is the real fun part of programming.

Answer (score 0):

The [for (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) would be a good place to start.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks. Might I add I do know how to use for on an extremely basic level, just can't find a way to print the numbers.

Comment: That link's first example includes how to do exactly that.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams Agreed.  Quite evident that he hadn't even bothered to look at the link you provided.  There's just no pleasing some people

Comment: Im coming along but the ladder is being printed with extra numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you answer to the first assignement:

```
for(int i=1;i<=height;i++)
{
    Console.Write('\n');
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
}
```

That will give you number pyramid for the first part. Based on this, you can design the answer for second assignment. (Hint: use second loop to reduce the variable back to 1)

Comment: Not only does that not answer his first question, I think it's pretty poor offering solutions to an assignment where the intention of the assignment is to learn the language.

Comment: my apologies Stafford for the code error which I have corrected. I thought it would help OP if I give him direction in which he should work.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this, you need to use TWO loops. One embedded inside other.

Your first loop should run from 1 to 5 with variable say 'i' starting from 1 and ending at 5 incremented by 1.

The second/ inner loop should start from 1 and run till 'i' value of outer loop. say variable 'j' from 1.. to value of 'i' increment by 1 . Inside this loop, you just print whatever the value of j and at the end of loop print new line '\n'.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with a method, because I guess that's what you need to write.

```
public static void PrintNumberLadder (int height) {
    //your code here...
}
```

And you also need a variable that stores what number to print next. Maybe `printNext` is a good name. Now you need to go up the ladder for the `height` number of times. Use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++) {
    //code...
}
```

Each iteration of that loop would print a new line. Now remember the `printNext` variable? Initialize it to 1. That is where you want to start from ,right? Now we need to think about how to print each line. Let's use another loop! This time we want to print `printNext` number of times. Oh and you suddenly remembered that `printNext` has to be incremented each time we print a new line. So now the code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++, printNext++) {//See? here is how you increment printNext
    for (int j = 0 ; j < printNext ; j++) {

    }
    Console.WriteLine(); //starts a new line
}
```

Now what should you do in the inner loop? You guessed it,

```
Console.Write (j + 1);
```

Wait a minute, why `Write` instead of `WriteLine` and why `j + 1`? We use `Write` to make sure that the stuff printed will not go to the next line. If you use `WriteLine`, it would be something like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

We use j + 1 because j starts at 0. But your ladder starts at 1;

Now how do you go down the ladder? Let me give you a hint. Use the `Substring` method in the `String` class. Make a variable to store the string that you will be printing.